# How to get Html.DropDownList() to retain selected value on postback?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

A select element is generated using the following code in an MVC4 view

```
@Html.DropDownList(
"abPrintYearsMode",
new List<SelectListItem>{
  new SelectListItem { Text = "Lifetime", Value = "1" },
  new SelectListItem { Text = "Manual", Value = "2" }
},
new { @class = "required" }
)
```

which renders the following HTML

```
<select class="required" id="abPrintYearsMode" name="abPrintYearsMode">
  <option value="1">Lifetime</option>
  <option value="2">Manual</option>
</select>
```

How do I get the select element to retain the value selected by the user on a postback? Currently, the topmost option "Lifetime" is always selected after a postback even when the user select "Manual" option #2.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
@Html.DropDownListFor( x => x.abPrintYearsMode,
new List<SelectListItem>{
  new SelectListItem { Text = "Lifetime", Value = "1" },
  new SelectListItem { Text = "Manual", Value = "2" }
},
new { @class = "required", id= "abPrintYearsMode"}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting autopostback property to true?

Dropdown Box has the property autopostback whcih if set to true fires an event. So when ever user selects a different value in the combo box, an event will be fired in the server. i.e. a request will be send to the server

[Reference](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxButton_AutoPostBacktopic)

Comment: I don't want the dropdown list to initiate a postback.

Answer (score 0):

You need a property on the model that is used by the view that will contain the selected value  of the dropdown. It appears in your case this property needs to be:

```
public int abPrintYearsMode { get; set; }
```

Comment: Added the property to my model for the view, but when a postback occurs the select element option #1 "Lifetime" is still selected.